# Correctly Interpolate 4D Data (on Grid) using Python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

## GOAL

I have values `v` given at specific 3D coordinates `x y z`. The data is stored as a pandas dataframe:

```
          x      y       z         v
0     -68.5  68.50  -10.00  0.297845
1     -68.5 -23.29   61.10  0.148683
2     -68.5 -23.29   63.47  0.142325
3     -68.5 -23.29   65.84  0.135908
4     -68.5 -23.29   68.21  0.129365
    ...    ...     ...       ...
91804  68.5  23.29  151.16  0.118460
91805  68.5  23.29  153.53  0.119462
91806  68.5  23.29  155.90  0.120386
91807  68.5  23.29  139.31  0.112257
91808  68.5 -68.50  227.00  0.127948
```

[image]

I would like to find the values at new coordinates that are not part of the dataframe, hence I am looking into how to efficiently interpolate the data.

## What I have done:

Since the coordinates are on a grid, I can use [interpn](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interpn.html):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.interpolate import interpn

# Extract the list of coordinates (I know that they are on a grid)
xs = np.array(df["x"].to_list())
ys = np.array(df["y"].to_list())
zs = np.array(df["z"].to_list())
# Extract the associated values
vs = np.array(df["v"].to_list())
```

Reshape the data to fit the scipy function:

```
points = (np.unique(xs), np.unique(ys), np.unique(zs))
values= vs.reshape(len(np.unique(xs)), len(np.unique(ys)), len(np.unique(zs)))
```

To test the interpolation, I would like to see if I get the same values back, if I put in the same points as the original points:

```
request = (xs,ys,zs)
output = interpn(points, values, request)
```

... **BUT**

[image]

**I am wondering, what I am doing wrong??**

### Other:

#### Dataset

Please find the complete dataset here: https://filebin.net/u10lrw956enqhg5i

#### Visualization

```
from mayavi import mlab
# Create figure
fig = mlab.figure(1, fgcolor=(0, 0, 0), bgcolor=(0, 0, 0))

        
mlab.points3d(xs,ys,zs,output)
mlab.view(azimuth=270, elevation=90, roll=180, figure=fig)

# View plot
mlab.show()
```

Comment: I question the validity of your reshape of `values` based on the snippet of data you show. Try to place on a grid using the `return_inverse` argument to `np.unique`

Comment: @MadPhysicist Very good point. I was also suspecting this, but for now, I am not sure how to check the validity or to fix it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator.html#scipy.interpolate.LinearNDInterpolator

Comment: @jlandercy. That's much too general here. Interpolation on a grid is much simpler when it's available, and it's available.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect that your data, while on a grid, is not ordered so as to allow a simple reshape of the values. You have two solutions available, both involving reordering the data in different ways.

**Solution 1**

Since you're already using `np.unique` to extract the grid, you can get the correct ordering of `vs` using the `return_inverse` parameter:

```
px, ix = np.unique(xs, return_inverse=True)
py, iy = np.unique(ys, return_inverse=True)
pz, iz = np.unique(zs, return_inverse=True)

points = (px, py, pz)

values = np.empty_like(vs, shape=(px.size, py.size, pz.size))
values[ix, iy, iz] = vs
```

`return_inverse` is sort of magical, largely because it's so counterintuitive. In this case, for each element of values, it tells you which unique, sorted gross location it corresponds to.

By the way, if you are missing grid elements, you may want to replace `np.empty_like(vs, shape=(px.size, py.size, pz.size))` with either `np.zeros_like(vs, shape=(px.size, py.size, pz.size))` or `np.empty_like(vs, np.nan, shape=(px.size, py.size, pz.size))`. In the latter case, you could interpolate the `nan`s in the grid first.

**Solution 2**

The more obvious solution would be to rearrange the indices so you can reshape `vs` as you tried to do. That only works if you're sure that there are no missing grid elements. The easiest way would be to sort the whole dataframe, since the pandas methods are less annoying than `np.lexsort` (IMO):

```
df.sort_values(['x', 'y', 'z'], inplace=True, ignore_index=True)
```

When you extract, do it efficiently:

```
xs, ys, zs, vs = df.to_numpy().T
```

Since everything is sorted, you don't need `np.unique` to identify the grid any more. The number of unique `x` values is:

```
nx = np.count_nonzero(np.diff(xs)) + 1
```

And the unique values are:

```
bx = xs.size // nx
ux = xs[::bx]
```

`y` values go through a full cycle every `bx` elements, so

```
ny = np.count_nonzero(np.diff(ys[:bx])) + 1
by = bx // ny
uy = ys[:bx:by]
```

And for `z` (`bz == 1`):

```
nz = by
uz = zs[:nz]
```

Now you can construct your original arrays:

```
points = (ux, uy, uz)
values = vs.reshape(nx, ny, nz)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!  I have tried it, but I am getting the following error: TypeError: argument for empty() given by name ('shape') and position (position 0)

Comment: @henry. If forgot to append `_like` in my hurry. Fixed now

Comment: Wow, it works perfectly! Thank you so much for your help!! I will have to read up on the magical 'return_inverse' option as well as on the 'np.empty_like' function.

Comment: @henry. I've added an update. By the way `df['x'].to_numpy()` is infinitely better than `np.array(list(df['x']))`. And time you find yourself using list operations, including comprehensions, with numpy or pandas, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: Wow, thank you so much for the update! Very nice how you sort the values in the data frame prior to the reshape. Is the np.count_nonzero(np.diff(...)) method faster than the np.unique? Also, thanks for pointing out the ".to_numpy()" method. So convenient, I didn't know about it.

Comment: I am curious: Which solution is more efficient/generalizable do you think?

Comment: @henry. Np.unique is basically sort followed by diff. The first solution doesn't pre-suppose a grid. You'd have to time it to find out which is fastest